# Horizontal and vertical scrolling for a Text widget

Tags: python, scroll, tkinter, text-widget

I'm looking for a simple way (possibly through flags) to make a `Text` widget  scroll horizontally, when the typed text inside gets out of range. If you know a way, for scrolling vertically to, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Disable word wrap in the `Text` widget. The text will then scroll horizontally as you type past the end of the line:

```
try:
    from Tkinter import *    # Python 2
except ImportError:
    from tkinter import *    # Python 3

root = Tk()
t = Text(root, wrap=NONE)
t.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Vertical scrolling comes for free.

Comment: It worked firs try, no skrollbars but I can scroll with arrows left/right and up/and down, perfekt thanks!